# How to find the current in a complex circuit with nodal voltage sources?

Tags: parallel, series, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law

[image]

This is circuit. Not sure how to get V, and find current. Any help?

Comment: There's 6V across that resistor, 6V across those resistors, and 24V across that resistor. Not exactly the definition of "complex".

Comment: Well you could start by simplifying your circuit. That R2 and R3 branch look like they are in parallel with R4 .

Answer (score 1):

The indication "+18 V" at E2 is just a quick way to draw an 18 V voltage source between ground and node E2.

With that in mind you can solve this circuit using any of the following:

- Modified nodal analysis
- Mesh analysis
- Simplification (combining series and parallel resistors) and simple inspection.